# Finding parallels surface of revolution

Tags: differential-geometry

$$X(u,v)=(f(u)\cos(v),f(u)\sin(v),g(u))$$ where $v$ is the rotation angle around $z$ axis. What is the parallel of this surface of revolution?

Comment: What is your book's definition of a *parallel* on a surface of revolution?

Comment: A parallel of a surface of revolution is the intersection of the surface with a plane orthogonal to the axis of revolution.

Comment: OK, so what is the axis of revolution in your case? And then what is an arbitrary plane orthogonal to it?